# Error on source dataset with REST Connector in Azure Synapse pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-rest-api

I am using [Copy and transform data from and to a REST endpoint by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory) to load a file from my `Box.com` account to an `Azure Data Lake Gen2 (ADLSGen2)` container. I'm using Synapse pipeline with source as the `REST connector` where I've identified the Base URL in [step3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#create-a-rest-linked-service-using-ui) of the tutorial to be `https://api.box.com/2.0/files/:file_id/content` where file_id is the id of my file stored in Box.com (ref: [here](https://developer.box.com/guides/authentication/app-token/endpoints/)).

When I run the pipeline, I get the following error. **Question**: What I may be doing wrong and how can the issue be resolved?

```
 "errorCode": "2200",
     "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=RestSourceCallFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The HttpStatusCode 401 indicates failure.\nRequest URL: https://api.box.com/2.0/files/:984786751561/content\nResponse payload:,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
     "failureType": "UserError",
     "target": "Copy data1",
     "details": []
```

Comment: Hi @nam, HttpStatusCode 401 failure usually occurs if you do not have the required permissions to access the link. Can you please confirm if you were able to access the link?

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. A 401 could be due to an unauthorized access. In your tutorial, on step 3, as you mentioned, there is a test connection button. Please click it to make sure you are authorized.